# Verify if the following function is a probability mass function. $F(x) = (3/4)(1/4)^x$ where $x = 0, 1, 2, ...$

Tags: probability, statistics

Continuation..

- a.) $P(X=2) $
- b.) $P(X\leq 2) $
- c.) $P(X> 2) $
- d.) $P(X \geq 1) $

Hi guys! I'm in bit of a pinch as I've already substituted the values of $x$ and have constructed the table. Unfortunately, when I added the values, namely $3/4$, $3/16$, and $3/64$, I got $63/64$, a little bit shy of $1$. But the probabilities should be equal to $1$, is there a value for infinity? Or did I do something wrong? Help will be very much appreciated.

P.S I'm typing from my phone, sorry for any mistakes. 
Thanks again!

Comment: $x=0,1,2, \cdots$ means that $x$ is any integer, so also $4,5,6,$ etcetera.

Comment: **Hint:** for C): $P(X>2)=1-P(X=2)-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$ The keyword is converse probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes an infinite geometric series which could be evaluated using the formula $S= a/(1-r)$ where a is the first term and r is the constant ratio. The answer comes out to be $1$. The rest is trivial.